# Detect VirtualMachine.attach() / virtualMachine.loadAgent

Tags: java

I am trying to stop (or at least detect) other programs  injecting into mine. Here's how they're doing it:

```
VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd = /* my program */;
VirtalMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd);
vm.loadAgent(new File('custom-jar.jar')); /* their modified code */
vm.detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.80.doc/user/attachapi.html) link:

*A process using the Java Attach API must be owned by the same UNIX user ID as the target process. This constraint ensures that only the target process owner or root can attach other applications to the target process.*

That means: the "attacker" has probably full access to the system running the JVM in the first place. I guess there is really not much that can be done in terms of securing a system that is owned by somebody else already.

Comment: Yeah it's to prevent cheating in a game. I understand it'll be easy to bypass, but my players are using free public cheats - I only want to protect against these known public programs.

Comment: If you are not in control of the JVM, everything is possible. Even when you write code that tries to break such agents ... how do you prevent another type of agent written to disrupt your new code that you put in place? What would people prevent from manipulating the JVM so that it is already compromised during startup? I guess there is a reason why big game companies run their games on their **own** servers. If all important aspects of your game "only exist" on systems owned by your customers ... there is no way of stopping cheats in the long run.

Comment: I understand it's not going to stop it in the long run, it will however stop the majority of my userbase - as the people creating these cheats wouldn't be installing my mod containing this code.